# Increment a counter in database SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, estimote

I'm doing a project on estimote shoe sticker and I'm now doing database for the sticker. My issue is now how to set counter in database sqlite. Every once the sticker is picked up or clicked, in the database it will show an increment in count. I have post the codes for database and main activity below.

**NearablesDemoActivity.java**

```
 private void displayCurrentNearableInfo() {
    stickerdb = new Database_sticker(this);
    dbRow = stickerdb.getResult(currentNearable.identifier);
    dbRow.getId();
    dbRow.getIdentifier();
    count = stickerdb.getCount(currentNearable.identifier);
    dbRow.getCount();

    String desc = dbRow.getDesc().toString();
    dbRow.getCa().toString();
    dbRow.getSa().toString();
    String coo = dbRow.getCoo().toString();
    String sm = dbRow.getSm().toString();
    String price = dbRow.getPrice().toString();

    //Set the text to the TextView
    Desc.setText(desc);
    COO.setText(coo);
    SM.setText(sm);
    Price.setText("$" + price);
}
```

**Database_sticker.java**

```
public int getCount(String identifier) {
    String countQuery = "UPDATE" + TABLE_SRESULT + " SET " + KEY_COUNT + "=" + KEY_COUNT + "+1"
            + " WHERE " + KEY_IDENTIFIER + "='" + identifier + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
        cursor.close();
    }
    return cursor.getCount();
}


public Sresult getResult(String identifier) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SRESULT + " WHERE " + KEY_IDENTIFIER + "='" + identifier + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();   //open database
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    //looping through all rows and adding to list
    Sresult sresult = new Sresult();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            sresult.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            sresult.setIdentifier(cursor.getString(1));
            sresult.setDesc(cursor.getString(2));
            sresult.setSa(cursor.getString(3));
            sresult.setCa(cursor.getString(4));
            sresult.setCoo(cursor.getString(5));
            sresult.setSm(cursor.getString(6));
            sresult.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(7)));
            sresult.setCount(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return sresult;
}
```

**ListNearablesActivity.java**

```
beaconManager.setNearableListener(new BeaconManager.NearableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNearablesDiscovered(List<Nearable> nearables) {
                toolbar.setSubtitle("Found shoes: " + nearables.size());
                adapter.replaceWith(nearables);
                for (Nearable nearable : nearables) {
                    if (nearable.isMoving) {
                        try {
                            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY));
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListNearablesActivity.this, clazz);
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_NEARABLE, adapter.getItem(nearables.indexOf(nearable)));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } //close for try
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Finding class by name failed", e);
                        } //close for catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                    }
                }
            } //for override
        });  //for beaconManager.setNearable



private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener createOnItemClickListener() {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                if (getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY) != null){
                    try {
                        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY));
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ListNearablesActivity.this, clazz);
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_NEARABLE, adapter.getItem(position));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } //close for try
                    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Finding class by name failed", e);
                    } //close for catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                } //close for getintent.getStringExtra()
            } //close for public void onitemclick
        };   //close for return new adapterview
    }  //close for private adapter
```

---

**Solution**

**Database_sticker.java**

```
 public int getStickerCount(String identifier) {
        String countQuery = "UPDATE " + TABLE_SRESULT + " SET " + KEY_SCOUNT + " = " + KEY_SCOUNT + "+1" + " WHERE " + KEY_IDENTIFIER + "= '" + identifier + "'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int scount = 0;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                scount = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(8));
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return scount; }
```

Comment: do you mean update `KEY_COUNT` + 1 ?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @calvinfly, I have made edits to the code but the application still crash when I click on the button

Answer (score 2):

For incrementing value by one in counter , you need to fire UPDATE query to Table.

Like below :

```
UPDATE "Your tablename"
SET "counter column name"= "counter column name"+ 1
WHERE id= "pass your reference id";
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, I have add in the following codes, please take a look and see if there is anything that needs improvement or changes

Comment: String countQuery = "UPDATE " + TABLE_SRESULT + " SET " + KEY_COUNT + " = " + KEY_COUNT + "+1"
            + " WHERE  " + KEY_IDENTIFIER + "= " + identifier + "'";
Log.e("countQuery",countQuery)

Comment: There's still error even though adding in those codes

Comment: What  is countQuery ?

Comment: Hi, I've already solve the problem, I will update the solution